# NSUserAppleScriptTask and Script Monitor

Tags: macos, applescript

I am wondering why some users of our app ghostnoteapp.com see the Script Monitor icon in their menu bar and others, including myself do not.

According to the AppleScript release notes

" (Script Monitor appeared in previous system releases, but was only used for Automator workflows; it now displays any script run using NSUserScriptTask, which includes anything run from Script Menu.)”

if it truly displayed any task ran via NSUserScriptTask, I would think it would for subclasses as well.
I can’t replicate the issue locally, so I’m in the dark/

Does anyone know under what circumstances executing a script causes this to appear?